# Why is my Minecraft PE gamer tag invisible?

Tags: technical-issues, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm not sure why, but when I was trying to change my name it glitched out, and now I can't type anything as my name.

If I try to chat with other players, all that appears in the game is "<".

Does anyone know how to fix this? I'd like to be able to communicate and have my name back.

Comment: Could be a server issue and that your name was not transmitted properly? Or perhaps you didn't enter a name in the first place? | Also, could you include more information? (Like debug logs, if any - iOS 5.0+ stores them somewhere...)

Comment: My name was actually fine before, I had used the same name for a while and wanted to change it. When I went to change it the typing option stopped working and nothing would show up when I typed my name.

Comment: Hi @Sarah, what platform are you playing this on? Have you tried restarting your device (phone/tablet etc)?